# Ionic get data from URL

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Hello here is my ionic info,

[image]

I'm trying to get data from url it's return `json` object. however i'm using `@angular/http`. this is perfectly working when execute in the browser (`ionic serve`). but when i run this apk on real android device the data didn't get from the url. 
Here is my code,

```
 this.http.get('https://example.com/api?search='+this.searchInput.value).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
      this.postalCode = data.data;
  },error => { 
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'error',
      subTitle: error,
      buttons: ['Dismiss']
    });
    alert.present();
  });
```

My config.xml,

```
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

My error is,

[image]

please let me know any configuration need to be done here ?

Comment: What's your error?

Comment: wait i ll edit this question with error

Comment: This might be CORS issue.

Comment: Can you try to generate an APK with --debug flag, in order to remote debug it and see response data. I agree with @MangeshDaundkar about possible CORS issue

Comment: is this common issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ionic,

> If you are using broswer as a test environment you must enable
>   cross-origin resource share in your browser befor use this function.

This is the way i solve this issue,

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

export class HomePage {
  ServerData: any;

  constructor(
    private HttpAngularProvider: Http,
    private HttpNativeProvider: HTTP,
    .....

  ) {
    this.getPostalCodeFromServer();
  }


  getPostalCodeFromServer() {
    if (this.platform.is('android') || this.platform.is('ios')) {

      this.HttpNativeProvider.get('your_url', {}, { "Content-Type": "application/json" })
        .then(data => {
          var dataReturn = JSON.parse(data.data);
          this.ServerData = dataReturn.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {

        });
    } else {
      this.HttpAngularProvider.get('your_url').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        this.ServerData = data.data;

      }, error => {

      });
    }
  }
```

In real device you need to make http request through the ionic-native. otherwise you didn't recive data.